# Could we make this one-liner any more concise?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, lambda, roslyn

I was wondering if I could use C# more like JavaScript to shortcut code. I tried to make the following code in fewer lines:

```
public async Task<bool> EnsureAuthenticated()
{
    if (!IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (!(await Authenticate()).IsSuccess)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        };
    }
    return true;
}
```

Which became:

```
public async Task<bool> EnsureAuthenticated()
{
    Func<bool> throwException = () => { throw new AuthenticationException(); };
    return IsAuthenticated || (await Authenticate()).IsSuccess || throwException();
}
```

And the closest I could get to a one-liner is:

```
public async Task<bool> EnsureAuthenticated()
{
    return IsAuthenticated || (await Authenticate()).IsSuccess ||
    ((Func<bool>)(() => { throw new AuthenticationException(); }))();
}
```

It is still too much code compared to equivalent code in JavaScript (or EcmaScript 2017 if you take async/await into account). But my question is mostly about the lambda part `((Func<bool>)(() => { throw new AuthenticationException(); }))()`.

Isn't there any more concise way to do this in C#, or C# vNext?

Comment: What's the use of making it more concise? You could extract out a method and call the method in the `return` statement.

Comment: @Blip No use really other than learning compiler behavior, and maybe readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, C# 7 *does* allow you to do something like you're describing, by allowing the use of `throw` in the 2nd or 3rd operand of the conditional operator (`?:`). So you could write your method like this:

```
public async Task<bool> EnsureAuthenticated()
{
    return (IsAuthenticated || (await Authenticate()).IsSuccess)
        ? true
        : throw new AuthenticationException();
}
```

However, it looks like you're trying to turn your readable code into the equivalent of bad (barely readable) JavaScript code, with some extra unreadability added on top on account of forcing that coding style into C#.

You can just do this; it's straightforward:

```
public async Task<bool> EnsureAuthenticated()
{
    if (!IsAuthenticated && !(await Authenticate()).IsSuccess)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException();
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can use DeMorgan's law to eliminate one of the `!`s:

```
public async Task<bool> EnsureAuthenticated()
{
    if (!(IsAuthenticated || (await Authenticate()).IsSuccess))
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException();
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when you think about it, the return value is pretty pointless if it only has one possible value, so you can eliminate it. The two possible outcomes then become (1) throw or (2) not throw instead of (1) throw or (2) return `true`:

```
public async Task EnsureAuthenticated()
{
    if (!(IsAuthenticated || (await Authenticate()).IsSuccess))
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException();
    }
}
```

Of course, if you decided you were ok with the function returning `true` or `false` instead of throwing an exception, then it becomes very simple and concise:

```
public async Task<bool> EnsureAuthenticated()
{
    return IsAuthenticated || (await Authenticate()).IsSuccess;
}
```

Comment: +1: This is good advice, particularly when you consider, `ensure authenticated`, doesn't convey the method returns a boolean.